# HTTP Authentication PHP

Tags: php, http, authentication

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

I got this code from php.net

is it possible to set target folder(or URL), userID and password?
I don't want to show popup login window to user

for example)

after line of header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

```
header('URL:./target_folder/')
header('UserID:guest')
header('Password:guest')
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please elaborate a bit, your question as is makes little sense.

Comment: If you mean you need to define a username and password, this is done through your webserver and not via PHP.

Comment: Reading tea leaves here... You want to *redirect* to a different URL with the username/password already "pre-filled"...?! If so, then what's the point of using authentication in the first place?

Comment: deceze// give a permit access when web login(php-MySQL)

Comment: You're still not making much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but you can pass your username and password in the URL like this :

`https://username:password@www.example.com/path`

It will not display any login popup.

Doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basic_access_authentication

Be aware of the Security section

> The BA mechanism provides no confidentiality protection for the transmitted credentials. They are merely encoded with BASE64 in transit, but not encrypted or hashed in any way. Basic Authentication is, therefore, typically used over HTTPS.